# Solenoid force to stroke equation

Tags: electromagnetism, solenoid

What does the variable "k" mean in the solenoid equation in the picture attached?
Many thanks for the help.
[image]

Source: [Theory & Practice of Electromagnetic Design of DC Motors & Actuators](http://www.consult-g2.com/course/chapter11/chapter.html)

George P. Gogue & Joseph J. Stupak, Jr.

Comment: Link to the original document?

Comment: http://www.consult-g2.com/course/chapter11/chapter.html

Comment: @MartinK The equations are immediately above the curve. Can't you guess, just by inspection, the implied meaning of \$k\$? Just look up slightly and I think you can see the factors in play there. (Nice page, by the way.)

Comment: See the link, equations 11.41 and 11.50.

Comment: so k=Uo/2*Ag*n^2*i^2  ???
Sorry but I am not good at maths :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help: -

Force = \$(N\cdot I)^2\cdot 4\pi 10^{-7}\cdot \dfrac{A}{2g^2}\$

- F = Force
- I = Current
- N = Number of turns
- g = Length of the gap between the solenoid and the magnetizable metal
- A = Area

If current, area and turns are constant, Force is inversely proportional to the gap squared (\$\ell^2\$). Formulas taken from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101127/powerful-electromagnet/101136) question.