# Solenoid Actuator (Linear) Force Calculation

Tags: control, solenoid, induction

what is the simplest form of law to calculate Solenoid electromagnetic force.
i.e. a relation between force and electric current
knowing that i'm given a Force constant with measuring unit N/A^2 (newton per ampere^2)

Comment: i googled but i couldn't find a law that contains the constant i was given in the assignment

Comment: + i need the simplest form

Comment: [Try this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/360596/solenoid-force-to-stroke-equation/360668#360668).